# Angular 8 - How to capture checkbox value on submit in the form of array of object

Tags: html, angular

I have some checkbox in the structure of parent child,I need to capture/console the value of checkbox based on selection in the output format( already given in the code as output as a hardcoded format). Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```
<p>home works!</p><div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">
    <ul>
        <li class="parentNav">parent1</li>
        <li class="childData">
            <ul>
                <li>child11<span class="pull-right"> <input checked type="checkbox"></span></li>
                <li>child12<span class="pull-right"> <input checked type="checkbox"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li class="parentNav">parent2</li>
        <li class="childData">
            <ul>
                <li>child2<span class="pull-right"> <input checked type="checkbox"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li class="parentNav">parent3</li>
        <li class="childData">
            <ul>
                <li>child3<span class="pull-right"> <input type="checkbox"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div><button (click)="submit()" type="submit">submit</button></div>

</div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  getListData: any;
  constructor(private commonserviceService: CommonserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.getHeroes();
  }
  submit(){
      alert('hi');
      console.log([{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},{"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]}]);
  }
getHeroes(){
   this.commonserviceService.getData().subscribe(getListData =>{
          this.getListData = getListData;
          console.log(this.getListData);
      },
      (error) => {
      alert('No data');
      }
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really, Uiappdeveloper, your question is a bit confused , so I must suppose you has a model like

```
model=[{"name":"parent1","value":["child11","child12"]},
       {"name":"parent2","value":["child2"]},
       {"name":"parent3","value":["child31","child32"]}]
```

And a data like, e.g.

```
data = [
    { name: "parent1", value: ["child11", "child12"] },
    { name: "parent2", value: ["child2"] }
  ];
```

And you want to show a list of checkBox as you show in the example. The first we need is a function that received "data" and create a FormArray of FormArray, based in the model and in the data

```
  getFormArray(value: any[]) {
    return new FormArray(
      this.model.map((x, index) => {
        const data = value ? value.find(d => x.name == d.name) : null;

        return new FormArray(
          x.value.map(
            c => new FormControl(data ? data.value.indexOf(c) >= 0 : false)
          )
        );
      })
    );
  }
```

And our .html that show the "model" and the "data"

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="leftNavBar">
  <form [formGroup]="formArray" (submit)="submit(formArray)">
  <ul *ngFor="let array of formArray.controls;let i=index">
    <li class="parentNav">{{model[i].name}}</li>
    <li class="childData">
      <ul *ngFor="let control of array.controls;let j=index">
        <li>{{model[i].value[j]}}
          <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="control">

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
    <div><button  type="submit">submit</button></div>
</form>
```

See that the formArray.value is only an array of arrays with values true or false, and see how we use the variables over we iterate "array" and "control" to write [formControl]="control".

Well, our formArray.value can be in a moment like

```
[ [ true, true ], [ true ], [ false, false ] ]
```

How transform in the object we want?. For this we can use the submit function, some like

```
  submit(formArray: FormArray) {
    const result = this.model.map((x: any, index) => {
      return {
        name: x.name,
        value: x.value.filter((v, j) => formArray.at(index).value[j])
      };
    });
    this.result = result.filter(x => x.value.length > 0);
    //in this.result we has the object we want
  }
```

You can see in action in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1sgrst?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer for checkbox its working fine but for radio box if I use html, <li>{{model[i].value[j]}}
          <input type="radio" name="{{model[i].name}}" value="{{model[i].value[j]}}" [formControl]="control">

        </li>  ..expected output is not coming properly

Comment: a radio button is a unique FormControl, not a FormArray. You need ask you: what data I need?, what data I has?, what model I has? It's impossible for me imagine your data. In my code I use **model** to create a FormArray using map. In general you'll has a model and create a FormGroup that show in .html